# UITextField - Get text before editing changed

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I set my text field to accept integer only but want to use UITextField inheritance rather than delegate of `shouldChangeCharactersInRange`.

Is there any way to get text value before `editingChanged` called as using `dropLast()` won't work in case the typed-in character is not at the last position.

```
class TextFieldInteger: UITextField {

    // A character set with number digits only
    let decimalRange = CharacterSet.decimalDigits

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(editingDidBegin), for: .editingDidBegin)
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(editingChanged), for: .editingChanged)
    }

    func editingDidBegin() {
        // Remove all existing "," from the input if having any
        input = input.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: "")
    }

    func editingChanged() {        
        if input.characters.count > 0 {
            let textSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: input)
            if !decimalRange.isSuperset(of: textSet) {
                input.dropLast()
            }
        }
    }
}

extension UITextField {
    var input: String {
        get { return text ?? "" }
        set { text = newValue }
    }
}
```

Comment: Make the text field its own delegate then. The delegate is how you do this so no use pretending it isn't.

Comment: Editing changed doesn't necessarily means a character was added at the end of the string

Comment: @LeoDabus, yes, that's why I said it won't work if it's not at the last position.

Comment: Good idea, thanks @matt.